# What is the etymology of the term "reduction" in the context of "reducing problem A to problem B?"

Tags: terminology

I teach a theory of computation course and each quarter a student asks me about why reductions between problems are called "reductions."  I am not fully sure why this is - saying that "problem A reduces to problem B" often involves turning a seemingly "easier" problem (for example, determining whether a string is in a regular language) into a much "harder" problem (for example, the halting problem) - and the terminology is often a great source of confusion to students.

Is there a historical reason why reductions are called reductions?  Is this term related to some other term in mathematics?

Thanks!

Comment: I rather suspect it is called that because *most of the time*, the problem you “reduce” the given problem to is either easier, or its solution is already known. And the latter is just another variety of “easier”.

Comment: I don't know, but our sometimes odd use of the term forms the basis for most of the jokes on this page: http://jcdverha.home.xs4all.nl/scijokes/6_2.html